Energy in simple harmonic oscillator in a moving frame of reference
It is pretty straightforward to derive the kinetic energy and the potential energy of a simple harmonic oscillator and to see that they behave like the squares of two sinusoids with a phase difference of $\pi/2$ (e.g. here). Then you go on to square those and show that the total energy is constant. But what happens if the frame of reference is moving at constant speed wrt to the center of the oscillator? I would expect that the total energy is still a constant (although a different value than the case where the frame of reference is fixed), but doing the math I find that

the the potential energy is still the square of a sinusoid as expected
the kinetic energy (which depends on the velocity of the oscillator) is no longer the square of a (zero mean) sinusoid because the velocity now has a constant component in this new frame of reference so the kinetic energy is the square of a sinusoid with a non-zero mean

I'm sure that I'm missing something but I don't know what.

The potential energy for a harmonic oscillator is a quadratic, not a sinusoid…

@MattHanson I think the OP is referring to the potential energy as a function of time for a classical SHO.

Ahhh I see. I thought you meant the PES itself for the spring.

I don't understand the downvotes. The first thing that you are missing is:
This is no longer the classic Simple Harmonic Oscillator! Yes, it can be transformed into one, but as is: it is not.
To understand work and kinetic energy in a moving frame, I strongly recommend studying a frictionless mass sliding down an inclined plane..if the plane's height is $h$, the potential energy changes by $mgh$, and in the rest frame $(v_i, v_f) = (0, \sqrt{2gh})$, for a kinetic energy change of:
$$ \Delta T = \frac 1 2mv_f^2 - \frac 1 2 mv_i^2 $$
$$ \Delta T = \frac 1 2 mv_f^2 = mgh $$
while in a frame moving at $u$, the KE goes from:
$$\frac 1 2 m u^2 \rightarrow \frac 1 2 m (\sqrt{2gh} + u)^2 $$
for a change in kinetic energy of:
$$ \Delta T' = \Delta T + mu\sqrt{2gh} $$
and that extra is due to the work done by the wedge's horizontal force ($F$) times the distance over which it is applied:
$$ \Delta x' = u\Delta t $$
then you can compute $\Delta t$, the time it takes to slide down, and it all works out.
Sooo....how do we deal with an SHO with a Galilean boost?
First start at rest, and to match the wedge case, start at max potential energy $U$, so:
$$ x(t) = L\cos\omega t $$
where:
$$ \omega^2 = \frac k m $$
Then:
$$ v(t) = \omega L \sin\omega t $$
$$ a(t) = -\omega^2 L\cos\omega t = -\omega^2 x(t) $$
so that the force is:
$$ F(t) = ma(t) = -m\omega^2x(t) = -kx(t) $$
omg, I reproduced Hooke's law the slow way.
From here, boost that using the insight from the wedge, as see what happens. I'll work on it later, (but in the meantime, you can provide the answer in a comment):
Edit: OK, it is later. Let's have a picture from the web:


We can look at the power applied by the spring in the "at rest" frame ($S$):

$$ P(t) = F(t)\dot{x}(t) = -kx(t)\dot{x}(t) $$
$$ P(t) = -k(L\cos\omega t)(\omega L\sin\omega t) $$
$$ P(t) = -\frac 1 2 k\omega L^2 \sin 2\omega t \equiv P^{SHO}_{k, m, L}(t)$$
which all makes sense: it's proportional to frequency (since going from energy to power, you pick up a factor of $1/T$ (period)), it goes as amplitude squared, and since it doesn't care about direction, the frequency is $2\omega$, and it is signed because the spring giveth KE and taketh KE away (with zero average, as it must be).
Whether it's linear in $k$ depends on how you count powers, since:
$$ k\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k^3} m}$$
and I don't have any intuitive reason why something goes as $k^{\frac 3 2}$.
Anyway, I'm calling that $P^{SHO}_{k, m, L}(t)$, a standard function of time depending on $k, m, L$.
Now we can look at that from a moving frame ($S'$). I will use $\beta$ because it's distinctive (versus $u$ or an overload $v$), but by no means am I doing a Lorentz transform. We're doing a Galilean transform:
$$ t \rightarrow t' $$
$$ x \rightarrow x' = x + \beta t = x + \beta t' $$
(Note: If $\beta < wL$, then the minimum KE will not occur at an oscillation extremum...which should show up in whatever comes next, so be on the look out for that.)
We get:
$$ x'(t) = L\cos\omega t + \beta t $$
$$ \dot x'(t) = \omega L\sin\omega t + \beta $$
Before computing power, we have to modify the force equation (which is how I opened: this is not a simple harmonic oscillator in $S'$):
$$ F'(x') = -kx = -k(x'-\beta t) $$
so the power input to the mass from the spring is:
$$P'(t) = F'(t)\dot{x}'(t) $$
$$P'(t) =  -k(x'-\beta t)(\omega L\sin\omega t + \beta) $$
$$P'(t) =  -k(L\cos\omega t)(\omega L\sin\omega t + \beta) $$
$$P'(t) =  P^{SHO}_{k, m, L}(t) - \beta kL\cos\omega t $$
which is the normal oscillator power exchange and a term due to frame motion:
$$ P^{Frame}_{\beta;k,m,L} =  - \beta kL\cos\omega t $$
which is linear in $\beta$ (that makes sense), $k$ (that also makes sense, since $k$ scales force), and finally linear in amplitude, $L$, which may make sense, I'm just noting it because it is not squared.
Finally, its oscillatory period is not doubled because forward and backwards (as defined by the sign of $\beta$) are not related by a reflection of coordinates, they are physically different.
Finally: I think this a good problem full of (pardon the expression) "teachable moments". The OP was not Pulitzer Prize level writing, but was completely understandable.

Hey I think the downvotes are because I wrote in a hurry and the question is poorly worded and I didn't write explicit formulas, but you understood exactly my point so all good. OK I think I understand the case of the mass sliding down an inclined plane: the wedge's horizontal force is there both in the rest frame and in the moving frame, but in a moving frame its work is non zero so it needs to be factored in. Also in the SHO case I have a feeling I'm missing some "reaction" force but I can't see what exerts the reaction force as there is only one body in my problem... right?

So in the SHO the kinetic energy in the frame at rest is $T(t) = \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2L^2sin^2(\omega t)$ while in the moving frame it is $T(t) = \frac{1}{2}m(\omega Lsin(\omega t)+u)^2$ so I understand the difference in the kinetic energy between the two frames is $mu\omega Lsin(\omega t)$ which depends on time t, so there seems to be some extra work in the moving frame case. How to account for that extra work?
